# Flutter Onboarding User Walkthrough

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I've seen a lot of flutter packages for onboarding users which are basically no more than just a slide deck. For example here is one: https://pub.dev/packages/introduction_screen

However, I am looking for something a bit more interactive. I'd like for the user to follow along with the tutorial. I've seen onboarding handled this way in a lot of websites, such as seen below:

[image]

Is there a pre-built package or easy way to mimic this type of interactive, user onboarding process in flutter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a package `tutorial_coach_mark:` that you can use to create a beautiful and easy tutorial for your application. It'll help you in a more interactive onboarding.

Check it out here: https://pub.dev/packages/tutorial_coach_mark

There is also another package: `highlighter_coachmark:`
but it might not be null safe.

If you don't want to rely on external packages, I'll recommend looking up this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62831798/11690853)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for :)